# How do I pass data to Base Controller from any view in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to pass data to base controller from ajax but it's not working.
How I can do it?

My BaseController in core/MY_Controller

**My Base Controller:**

```
<?php 
    class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    public $site_data;
    function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
    }

    public function user_data_submit() {
      $abc=$this->input->post('name');
      $data = array(
      'no' => $this->input->post('name')
        );

      //$data2["a"]=$abc;
       /*$return["json"] = json_encode($return);
        echo json_encode($return);*/
      echo json_encode($abc);
  }}
```

**My Ajax:**

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "MY_Controller/user_data_submit",
  dataType: 'json',
  data: { name: ogrno },
  success: function(data) {
    if (data) {
      // Show Entered Value
      alert(data);
      $("#notifications #bsayisi").text('');
    }
  }
});
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. The main issue is trying to use `MY_Controller` directly. I'll explain what you need to do but first you need to correct some issues in `MY_Controller`.

There is a problem with what you are passing to `json_encode()`. And your ajax call needs some fixing - as shown there are too many lines of `});`. (Maybe that is because of code you don't show. If so, then ignore me.)

It is assumed that `ogrno` is a var previously defined. If not, fix that too.

Try this javascript

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "MY_Controller/user_data_submit",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {name: ogrno},
    success: function (data) {
        if (data)
        {
            // Show Entered Value
            alert(data);
            //next line commented out because your intent is unclear
            //$("#notifications #bsayisi").text('');
        }
    }
});
```

This should fix the controller.

```
public function user_data_submit()
{
    $data = array('no' => $this->input->post('name'));
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

You cannot use `MY_Controller` directly just like you cannot use `CI_Controller` directly. To use `MY_Controller` you must "extend" a new controller using `MY_Controller`. For example...

```
class Welcome extends MY_Controller { ...
```

The `Welcome` controller will now be able to use the method `user_data_submit()`

However, the `url` option in the ajax call will now fail because "MY_Controller" isn't where the call needs to go. It needs to go to `welcome`. The value needs to be the controller extending `MY_Controller`. The [PHP Magic Constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) `__CLASS__` provides the solution to getting the name of the extending class.

```
url: "<?php echo base_url(__CLASS__); ?>" + "/user_data_submit",
```

`__CLASS__` will always be the name of the class extending `MY_Contoller`.

Comment: i want to pass base controller my basecontroller name MY_Controller is in application/core

Comment: i pass to data to base controller, my base controller not in application/controller it is in the application/core so  getting error this at  url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "MY_Controller/user_data_submit",

Comment: See the revised answer.